# How to verify that a checkbox is just about to be unchecked?

Tags: android, checkbox

In Android, is this code rith to verify that the checkbox is clicked to be unchecked ?

```
      public void onClick(View v) {

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(IdentifyActivity.this, "clicked to check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(IdentifyActivity.this, "clicked to uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `OnCheckedChangeListener`. you have to implement the callback

```
 onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
```

that's the way your task is usualy done. Your code works as well and, probably, between both approces there is not a real difference

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);

cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // It's checked
        } else {
            // It's not checked
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked==true)
         {
           //your checkbox is checked
          }
        else
         {
            //your checkbox is not checked
          }

   }
}
```